# append HTML from file with Cheerio, NodeJs

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, append, cheerio

I am trying to append some html from a file to some existing html with cheerio but i keep getting errors (the errors are being produced by the cheerio library so debugging is hard)

```
expo.includeNav = function(html, result)
{
    var file = 'templates/admin_nav.html';

    fs.readFile(file, function(err, nav)
    {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        $('body').append(nav);
        result($.html());

    });

}
```

It dosen't seem to like passing a variable into the append function.

If i put the html in instead of calling from a file it works, like so:

```
$('body').append('<div class="nav"> navigation list here</div>');
```

But i do not want that as i want front end devs to be able to edit an HTML file instead of digging into my node JS code to find where to change the html.

Comment: What is the value of `nav`?

Comment: i will add the value of nav to my question now.

Comment: I have added to the question :)

Comment: If i minify that HTML and paste it onto .append('') it works fine.

Comment: iv found that using $('body').html(nav); works, however cheerio uses $.html() so its skrewing up the rest of hte page... suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'v worked it out. I assume someone else may run into this issue as i could see it being a common need. so here is the answer.

You need to specify that you want it returned as a string instaed of a buffer. do this with 'utf8'

```
expo.includeNav = function(html, result)
{
    var file = 'templates/admin_nav.html';

    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, nav)
    {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        $('body').append(nav);
        result($.html());

    });

}
```