# Replace <head></head> in html

Tags: html, cheerio

How can I replace head tag in html with my own provided code using cheerio?

The html structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

Example html doc......

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But… but… why? There is exactly a single use case that I can come up with, that is HTML e-mail templates. What problem do you try to solve?

Comment: You would not want to change the `<head>` itself, but its `innerHTML`...

Comment: Do you mean similar to the solution for this: [Append HTML with Cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602260/append-html-from-file-with-cheerio-nodejs), except `$("head").append(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to add something after it, and then remove it:

```
$('head').after('<div></div>').remove()
```

To change the innerHTML use html():

```
$('head').html('new html')
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I decided not to replace whole html code when its possible just to add 
there what I need and remove what I dont want. How it would be possible to select to what position the code would be appended using `$("head").append(...)`. I want to add async js script to the top of header.